Trying to solve a complex number question
Currently, I have been preparing for ioqm and this question came in a mock of it. Cant figure out whether the question gives sufficient information to solve it....
Here is the statement:
Suppose a, b, and c are three complex numbers with product 1. Assume that none of a, b, and c are real or have absolute value 1. Define:
$$ p = a + b + c + (1/a + 1/b+1/c)$$
$$ q = a/b + b/c + c/a $$
If both p and q are real then find q-p.....
Now according to question poser q = 3 and p = -3 is the only solution.
What I had tried was writing a , b , c in polar form and translation the conditions:
$$1:  r_1 r_2 r_3 = 1$$
$$2: p + q + r = 2n\pi $$
$$ 3 : \sum \sin (p)(r_i - 1/r_i) = 0 $$
$$ 4 : \sum (r_1/r_2)\sin(p-q) = 0$$
But solving it further turns out to be tough or insufficient info is there... really not sure.

"no question" ?

@JonathanZ "complex number question"

Ah. OP, please don't use abbreviations like that in your title.

Might not be a good idea to use $p,q,r$ for the angles; it collides with the $p,q$ from the problem and the $r$ for the radii. This led you to make some errors in equations 3 and 4.

I think the equations are correct, please correct me where I am wrong ?

I removed the tag [tag:complex-geometry]. See its description: *For elementary questions about geometry in the complex plane, use the tags [tag:complex-numbers] and [tag:geometry] instead. *

I think your $p$ and $q$ in the last formulas are different from those previously defined: if so please use different names.

I wanted to use alpha, beta or gamma but didn't knew how to write that in latex.

\alpha, \beta, \gamma ...

We have: $p=(a+b+c)+\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)$
$q=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{a}, abc=1$
Consider, $r=\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{a}{c}$
We notice $qr=3+\frac{1}{a^3}+\frac{1}{b^3}+\frac{1}{c^3}+a^3+b^3+c^3$
So:
$p^3=a^3+b^3+c^3+3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)+\frac{1}{a^3}+\frac{1}{b^3}+\frac{1}{c^3}+3\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)\left(\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)\left(\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{a}\right)+3(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)(p)$
So we have: $p^3=qr-3+6(q+r+2)+3(3+q+r)(p) \implies r(q+6+3p) \in \mathbb{R}$ as $p^3 \in \mathbb{R}$
Claim:- $r \notin \mathbb{R}$
pf:- FTSOC consider $r \in \mathbb{R}$
Consider $\left(a+b+c\right)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)=3+q+r$
So since $r \in \mathbb{R}$
we have $(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)$ and $(a+b+c)+\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right) \in \mathbb{R}$
hence we have two cases:
Case 1:- $(a+b+c) , \left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)=(ab+bc+ca)  \in \mathbb{R}$
If this is the case then we have the equation $z^3-(a+b+c)z^2+(ab+bc+ca)z-1=0$ has at least one real root $\implies$ at least one of $a,b,c$ is real which is a contradiction. Hence this case doesn't work.
Case 2:- $\overline{a+b+c}=ab+bc+ca=\Omega$
then since $abc=1$ we notice if $\omega$ is a root of $z^3-\overline{\Omega}z^2+\Omega z-1=0$ then $\frac{1}{\overline{\omega}}$ is also a root , which is contradiction as $|a|,|b|,|c| \neq 1$ and $\Im(a), \Im(b), \Im(c) \neq 0$. Hence this case also does not work.
So overall we observe no such case works and hence $r \notin \mathbb{R}$. So claim follows $\square$
so we must have $q+6+3p=0 \implies p^3-3pq-9p-6q-9=0$ , plugging $q=-3p-6$ we get $(p+3)^3=0 \implies p=-3, q=3$
hence we have $\boxed{(p,q)=(-3,3)}$ as the only pair. $\blacksquare$
Construction: $(a,b,c) =\left(-2i , \frac{-(i+2)}{2}, \frac{-(2i+1)}{5}\right)$ works.[/quote]
